# Sending large messages ( > 200MB) in Akka Cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-io

I have to send large messages of size around 200MB in akka-cluster from one actor to multiple actors. I have tried using the akka messaging but it times out as it is taking a long time.

What is the best way to implement this? I have read somewhere that we need to use Akka IO for such tasks but I couldn't find enough documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

General approach would be to serve big files using HTTP, Torrent or some other technology that is more suited for big file transport. Use akka to send only the addresses to the resources to all of the concerned actors.

Comment: I need to communicate in-memory objects. Is that possible using any of the approaches you mentioned?